# Parsing output of an ssh command using awk

Tags: ssh, awk, grep, cut, gerrit

I have an `ssh` command which gives the following output, I want the `ssh` command to be modified such that the `url` and `jirano` output comes side-by side if there is `jirano`, second change does not have `jirano`.. I have the expected output below.. can this be done using `awk` or `grep` or `cut`?

```
ssh -p 29418 review-android.company.com gerrit query --current-patch-set \
  --commit-message 'platform/vendor/qcom-opensource/data/code branch:bj_5.2 label:Verified=-1'
```

Output

```
change I739c56305aed3da40132253cf66bce4d315f73
  project: platform/vendor/qcom-opensource/data/code
  branch: bj_5.2
  id: I739c56305aed3da40132253cf66bce4d315f73
  url: https://review-android.company.com/12345
  commitMessage: data: test

         this is an experiment
         driver.  Since none of the definitions in this file are actually being
         used today, remove the file and all references to it.

         jirano: 470101
  createdOn: 2013-04-18 13:17:05 PDT
  lastUpdated: 2013-04-18 17:21:54 PDT
 change I739c56305aed3da401a5323cf66bce4d315f73
  project: platform/vendor/qcom-opensource/data/code
  branch: bj_5.2
  id: I739c56305aed3da401a532253cf66bce4d315f73
  url: https://review-android.company.com/67899
  commitMessage: test1

         this is an test
         donot experiment
         used today, 


  createdOn: 2013-04-18 13:17:05 PDT
  lastUpdated: 2013-04-18 17:21:54 PDT
```

Expected output

```
https://review-android.company.com/12345 470101
https://review-android.company.com/67899
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
$ awk '/url|jirano/{print $2}' foo.txt | sed 'N; y/\n/ /'
```

Result

```
https://review-android.company.com/12345 470101
https://review-android.company.com/67899
```

Comment: I dont think it is working...am seeing the url is getting printed side-by-side when there is no "jirano" filed

Comment: how to make jirano case-insensitive @'/url|jirano/{print $2}'

Comment: there might be or might not be a space after colon(:) "jirano: 470101" ..current command is messing up when there is no space after colon(:)